# Liferay Vaadin Portlet(s) with different versions

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin, vaadin7

I have to develope an Liferay (6.0.6) portlet and I have to use Vaadin.

I have to use Java 1.6 and I see in the Liferay setting Vaadin Info: I see something like Vaadin 6.7.7.

If I use Vaadin 6.7.7 and Java 1.6 I not have problems. I tried it.

But, can I use some latest vaadin version? For example, In my portlet can I use Vaadin 7.x ?

I can't to update Liferay Vaadin Version ...

So, in this Liferay portal, Can I implement portlet with different Vaadin version?

If this is possible, what is it this Liferay Vaadin version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use different Vaadin versions in Liferay, if you are careful:

- Package the Vaadin into the portlet war itself.
- Use the latest Vaadin 7.x version if possible (currently 7.3.6)
- Don't put two Vaadin portlets with different versions on the same page. The client-side GWT most likely does not work correctly.

Easiest is to setup the [Liferay IDE and use Vaadin Maven archetype](http://www.liferay.com/web/esami/blog/-/blogs/getting-started-with-vaadin-in-liferay) to generate your project. Note: most reliable is to use the archetype with latest Vaadin version e.g. `com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-liferay-portlet:7.3.6`. Also make sure you create a Maven profile for you local Liferay setup.